# SOTO Triple Mix Expiration

Tags: camping, canister-stoves

I have a SOTO Triple Mix canister (Power Gas 250, SOD-725T) which is a mixture of Butane, Isobutane and Propane gas. I use it with my SOTO WindMaster but I have not used it in over 10 months. It has been stored with the cap-on inside my closet which has air circulation and is a dark, cool environment. When I went to pick up the canister this morning, it sounded like liquid was slushing around inside.

Is this normal? I don't remember how it felt before and just want to make sure the gas didn't "go bad" or if there are any safety precautions I should be taking. There is no rust on the canister top since I had the plastic cap on when not in use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gas is compressed in the cylinder so will largely be a liquid. This is normal and expected.